# Why do I get an error message although I have installed thonny sqlite3 correctly

Tags: sqlite, thonny

I want to use thonny sqlite3. I am installing sqlite3 module with Thonny Manage Packages.But after typing `import sqlite3`, when I want to run it in this state, it gives the following error message:

```
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/lib/sqlite3.py", line 11, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'func'
```

Thank for your  help.